# How to map Revit external ids to Navisworks-based SVF

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

Is there an efficient to map Revit externalid value to a Forge SVF model that's been exported from Navisworks and therefore has the external id value in the "0/1/0/0" format type.

The built in externalid mapping is handy in Forge but it doesn't look like it can be used in this case, unless there's a way to tell forge what type of mapping is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Navisworks doesn't store Revit `Element.UnqueId` info in Naviworks model formats (NWC/NWF/NWD), which is the external id for the RvT file in APS viewer.

You might know that Navisworks supports various file formats. However, not all file formats have a GUID concept, according to our engineering team. This is also the reason why the external id of the Naviworks model in SVF uses the instance tree node path (saying e.g. 0/1/0/0")

If you just want to get a mapping between the RVT file and NWC file from the same Revit model, you can use Revit `ElementID` instead in this case.

- **For an element of the Revit model**: The ElementID can be found at the end of the object name (in SVF), or in the hidden properties called `ElementId`.

[image]
[image]

- **For an element of the Navisworks model generated from the same RVT**: You can find the ElementID in the properties of `Element.Id`.

[image]
[image]

Comment: would this type of mapping affecting performance, compared to the built-in externalmapping function?

Comment: Well, it's hard to say. It depends on the element amounts in your RVT file.